# Running more than Rails apps on a local Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I would like to set up multiple Rails apps running simultaneously.

I'm using a basic installation with Rails and Mongrel. I'm pretty newbie when it comes to a server side thing.

What kind of options do I have to run multiple Rails app running at the same time on a local Mac?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only thing that stops you from running multiple rails apps on one machine is the ports.

If you want to run several apps while developing just use `script/server -p <port number>` for each of the apps.

If you have a production machine set up, I would recommend you to use phusion passenger with apache or nginx, and set up different virtual machines (or ports)

Comment: Running separate ports by hand gets unmanageable fast when you have more than one or two projects. Passenger is the solution.

Comment: I agree, however, setting up passenger for development projects is a bit overkill. Usually you won't develop on more than one project anyway.

Answer (score 6):

If you end up using Phusion Passenger, the [Passenger Preference Pane](http://www.fngtps.com/passenger-preference-pane) can automatically configure your Apache virtual hosts for you. It's a lot easier than editing the Apache configuration and your `/etc/hosts` file each time you want to set up a new application.

Comment: Thanks for your infor. The pane seems very useful. I'll try it.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you start rails server using webrick or mongrel like

```
script/server
```

and

```
mongrel_rails start
```

respectively, that starts your server on port 3000 by default, ie. you can access your app on localhost:3000

To have multiple rails apps running on same machine, just start the servers by going to different rails application root directories on different ports like so

```
script/server -p 3001
```

or

```
mongrel_rails start -p 3001
```

Just for info, if you want to start rails apps in different environments then just pass -e option when you start the server like so

```
script/server -e production
```

or

```
script/server -e test_or_anyotherenv
```

If you don't give -e option, then it will by default start the server in development environment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Django (not Rails) coder, but I think you should launch the servers at **different ports**.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I used mongrel on different ports. Works just fine. But, as agregoire mentioned, Phusion Passenger and the Passenger PrefPane make your life so much easier. Checkout Ryan Bates's RailsCast, [Passenger in Development](http://railscasts.com/episodes/122-passenger-in-development), for a good tutorial on setting it up.